# Lock fullscreen app positions

Tags: macos, fullscreen

Is it possible (natively, or with a 3rd party tool), to lock the position of fullscreen apps in Lion?

My problem is... whenever I click on a fullscreen app in the dock, it takes me to that app, but it jumps to the front of the queue of fullscreen apps.

I would very-much like these apps to be locked in-place, so their positions can't be changed.

Is it possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is actually a quite easy fix to this:

1. Launch System Preferences.
2. Select "Mission Control."
3. Uncheck "Automatically rearrange spaces based on most recent use."